# Chartjs not reading data from vuex mapped state

Tags: chart.js, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I am using chartjs in a nuxt component.
The problem is, I am getting referrence error, chartLabels and chartDataPoints are not defined.
If I replace chartLabels and chartDataPoints with this.$store.state.chartLabels and this.$store.state.chartDataPoints, my chart gets rendered, but then, it is no longer reactive since I need to use computed for that.

The store has been set up properly, and I am getting the correct data in vue devtools so the store doesn't seem to be the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<canvas id="daily-chart"></canvas>
```

The chart is getting called in mounted() as so:

```js
mounted() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("daily-chart")
  new Chart(ctx, this.chartData)
},
```

Here is the chartData:

```js
chartData: {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: chartDataPoints,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    lineTension: 1,
  },
}
```

chartDataPoints and chartLabels are being fetched from the store's state:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState(['chartDataPoints', 'chartLabels'])
},
```

Comment: Did you `import { mapState } from 'vuex'`? Your module is maybe namespaced?

Comment: I did import mapState and no, I am not using any modules right now. Sorry, should have mentioned those as well. But yeah, the mapStates are working fine. As I mentioned, I am able to see the data changes in vue devtools... I think I am making some mistake in how I am supposed to use them in the chartData object.

Comment: How do you use your package? Because here it looks like you created the instance in `mounted()` and it's never touched again, aka is it reactive at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **vue-chart-js** you may want to declare your chartData inside a specific js file that you would put in your template file.

Here is an example :

```js
import {Line} from "vue-chartjs"

export default {
    extends: Line,
    data: function(){
        return {
      datacollection: {
                 labels: chartLabels,
                 datasets: [{
                      data: chartDataPoints,
                 }],
            },
            options: {
                 responsive: true,
                 lineTension: 1,
            },
     },

    props:{
   chartDataPoints : Array,
  },
 }
```

Then put the line chart in your template as :

```html
<template>
   <line-chart
      :chartDataPoints="charData"
    >
    </line-chart>
</template>
```

I would also recommand using [MapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) from *vuex* instead of mapState and putting this in to a computed properties.

```js
computed: {
   ...mapGetters({
     chartDataPoints : 'chartData/getChartDataPoints'
   })
},
```

And in your chartData.js (store) :

```js
export const state = () => ({
   charData: [],
})

export const getters = {

   getChartDataPoints: (state) => () => {
       return this.charData
   }

}
```

Then, you would change your template to :

```html
<template>
   <line-chart
     :chartDataPoints="chartDataPoints()"
   >
   </line-chart>
</template>
```

Comment: So the first code fragment is a plain helper .js file?
Also. Since in my case, both labels and data would be changing, I am assuming I should use both in props, and then modify the rest of the code accordingly.

I'll give it a shot. I tried something similar, and it helped a bit, but did not solve the problem completely. But I was not using a helper file, and I was still using mapState instead of getters.

Comment: Yes, it's in a js file. Then you can import it with : ```import lineChart from "@/components/your/path/lineChart.js"```